# jquery mostrar y ocultar elementos con click, interfiere con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Me funcionaba perfecto hasta que use ajax.
Tienen ustedes alguna otra forma de hacerlo?
*Tienen bastantes filas de datos de #resultado seguidos de div.unicc

Quiero que al darle en el + abra el .unicc siguiente
Alguien que me de solucion por favor.

```js
$(".Mostrar_Tabla").click(function(){
  $trOcultar = $(this).parents(".todd").next(".unicc");

  if ($trOcultar.is(":visible")) {
      $trOcultar.css("display", "none");
  }
  else {
      $trOcultar.css("display", "");
  }
  
  //cuando use este ajax no funcionó más.
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'buscar.php' ,
  type: 'POST' ,
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {consulta: consulta},
 })
 .done(function(respuesta){
  $("#tabla_resultado").html(respuesta);
 })
 .fail(function(){
  console.log("error");
 });
}


$(document).on('keyup','#busqueda', function(){
 var valor = $(this).val();
 if (valor != "") {
  buscar_datos(valor);
 }else{
  buscar_datos();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
<div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
<div class="col-md-1">99903053</div>
<div class="col-md-1">50</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
Aqui esta un contenido oculto
 </div>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
<div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
<div class="col-md-1">99903054</div>
<div class="col-md-1">60</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
Aqui esta un contenido oculto
 </div>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
<div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
<div class="col-md-1">99903055</div>
<div class="col-md-1">20</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
Aqui esta un contenido oculto
 </div>
```

Comment: Cuando utilizas las función `buscar_datos(consulta)` estas utilizando un parámetro, pero cuando haces la llamada a dicha funciona no le mandas un parámetro, tiene eso algo que ver?

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es que el evento `click()` interfiera con el `$.ajax()` o viceversa sino que se te olvido  agregar el cierre de la instrucción  antes de ejecutar la función `$(buscar_datos());` que por cierto no es la forma adecuada de hacerlo.

```js
$(".Mostrar_Tabla").click(function() {
      $trOcultar = $(this).parents(".todd").next(".unicc");

      if ($trOcultar.is(":visible")) {
        $trOcultar.css("display", "none");
      } else {
        $trOcultar.css("display", "");
      }
    }); //esta linea es la que te faltaba

   buscar_datos(); //deberias llamar a la funcion de esta forma y no dentro del selector JQuery

    function buscar_datos(consulta) {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'buscar.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {
            consulta: consulta
          },
        })
        .done(function(respuesta) {
          $("#tabla_resultado").html(respuesta);
        })
        .fail(function() {
          console.log("error");
        });
    }


    $(document).on('keyup', '#busqueda', function() {
      var valor = $(this).val();
      if (valor != "") {
        buscar_datos(valor);
      } else {
        buscar_datos();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
  <div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
  <div class="col-md-1">99903053</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">50</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
  Aqui esta un contenido oculto
</div>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
  <div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
  <div class="col-md-1">99903054</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">60</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
  Aqui esta un contenido oculto
</div>
<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
  <div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
  <div class="col-md-1">99903055</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">20</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
  Aqui esta un contenido oculto
</div>
```

Comment: Lo copié tal cual y me sigue dando error.

Comment: @MarcoTorres cuando se realiza la función `buscar_datos` ¿Que debe recibir como valor de entrada?

Comment: `<div class="todd col-md-12" id="resultado">
  <div class="Mostrar_Tabla col-md-1"><b>+</b></div>
  <div class="col-md-1">99903055</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">20</div>
</div>
<div class="unicc" style="display:none;">
  Aqui esta un contenido oculto
</div>`

Estos 2 divs grandes.

Comment: @MarcoTorres  pero eso no se lo mandas, por eso te da el error entonces. Actualiza tu ejemplo le falta algunas cosas por ejemplo donde esta el tag de id búsqueda.